# Steampunk movie about Demons

Tags: identify-this-movie, anime

This Movie or series has a few key points.  I want to remember the name of it badly since I liked it so much years ago.  any help would be appreciated

1. set in a Steampunk world, dull, rainy.
2. Humans practice magic there but require protective suits else they become corrupt and turn into demons.
3. starts off with seemingly 2 protagonists, *SPOILER ALERT*  End up fighting each other when 1 uses too much magic in the fight and turns into a demon.
4. Main character has a small girl following him around, she has 4 eyes (since her mother was raped by a demon, resulting in her birth)

like I said, if anybody could answer this question "what is the name of this movie" you will make life so much easier since I can't remember it anymore by name or by those key points.  maybe you remember or might own it :)

Answer (score 6):

I think you're looking for [Strait Jacket](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2311880/), (2008).

> In a world where sorcery and science co-exist, the power of magic
>   comes with a price: Humans who do not take proper precautions are
>   transformed into horrific demons. Those who destroy these demons - and
>   run the highest risk of all - are tactical sorcerists known as Strait
>   Jackets.

It was shown as one of the Sci Fi Channel's Ani-Monday features.  The girl looked like she had two human eyes and two sort of reptilian eyes.

Comment: Sounds about right.